# Powerapps Add Item to lookup field refresh combobox choices

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-formula

I have two lists:

1. Projects
2. Contacts

I have a powerapp that let you add new projects, it has a lookup field for contacts.  In the app you can click add contact, create a new contact and submit.  It then returns you to the project page.

The new value isn't in the lookup for contacts until you refresh the page.

How do I add the value to the combobox and set it to the newly added value?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I was refreshing the contact field even though the lookup was to Project.Contact.  Once I updated the project field I'm golden.